# Combine 2 rows into 1 based on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I have 2 tables agreements & party. In table party, when indicator = 1 then party.c1 = agreements.c1 and party.b1 = agreements.b1; when indicator = 0 then party.c1 = agreements.c2 and party.b1 = agreements.b2. The values in agreements table are unique with all 4 columns combined.

```
agreements
c1       b1        c2       b2
1001     1         2001     1
1001     1         2001     2
1001     1         2002     1
1001     1         2003     1
1001     2         2004     1
1001     2         2004     5

party
c1       b1        indicator      id
1001     1         1              id-1
1001     2         1              id-2
2001     1         0              id-3
2001     2         0              id-4
2002     1         0              id-5
2003     1         0              id-6
2004     1         0              id-7
2004     5         0              id-8
```

I would like to form a row similar to agreements table for every combination of columns (c1, b1) and (c2, b2). In agreements table, (1001,1) is combined with (2001,1) as well as (2001,2), (2002,1) & (2003,1). Similarly, (1001,2) is combined with (2004,1) & (2004,5). So the target output is like this

```
c1    b1   indicator  id    c1    b1  indicator id
1001  1    1          id-1  2001  1   0         id-3
1001  1    1          id-1  2001  2   0         id-4
1001  1    1          id-1  2002  1   0         id-5
1001  1    1          id-1  2003  1   0         id-6
1001  2    1          id-2  2004  1   0         id-7
1001  2    1          id-2  2004  5   0         id-8
```

How can I achieve this, am using postgresql 12.

**Update 1:**
Updated sample data

TIA,
AK

Comment: The result you show does not match the description. Nor is the description clear. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does it.   (not tested)

```
select left_party.*
, right_party.*
from party left_party
join agreements on left_party.c1 = agreements.c1 and left_party.b1 = agreements.b1
join party right_party on agreements.c2 = right_party.c1 and agreements.b2 = right_party.c1
```

Comment: With this sample data it might not be an issue, but I figure the indicator part of the question needs factored in. In case party.c1 + party.b1 is not unique